# php - paginate facebook api

Tags: php, facebook, pagination

I have using facebook curl to get all feed in a group. The url like

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.10/ID_GROUP/feed?fields=full_picture,from,caption,description,message,updated_time,likes,type,source&limit=10&icon_size=16&access_token=TOKEN
```

Then my result when I json_decode this url, and I get an array like

```
"data" => array:10 [▼
0 => array:7 [▶]
1 => array:7 [▶]
2 => array:7 [▶]
]
```

And the link paginate is

```
"paging" => array:2 [▼
"previous" => "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.10/ID_GROUP/feed?fields=full_picture,from,caption,description,message,updated_time,likes,type,source&limit=10&icon_size=16 ▶"
"next" => "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.10/ID_GROUP/feed?fields=full_picture,from,caption,description,message,updated_time,likes,type,source&limit=10&icon_size=16 ▶"
]
```

I have an simple question. How can I paginate from this pagination url above ? I want to dipslay the page from page 1 to page 2, ... on the front end.

Please helps or give me an tutorial.

Thanks.

Comment: just use the url in the "next" field with curl to get the elements of the next page

Comment: Yes, I know that, but I don't know how to display on the front end. When the user press the page 2 (on the front end), how can I trigger the "next" field ?

Comment: do an ajax call to a php script that uses the next field with curl, or use the facebook javascript sdk to do the call. still not sure what the question is, to be honest. this sounds a bit too broad for stackoverflow.

Comment: Can you give me some tutorial for that. I know how to paginate with the database, but with the curl from facebook. This is the first time I use and I don't know how to do that.

Comment: you already did an api call (with the first url in your question). just do another api call with the url in the "next" field. what tutorial would you need for that, if you already have the code? if the user clicks on "next", to another api call with the "next" url, period.